# Error while trying to create a docker file for django

Tags: python, docker

```
FROM python: 3.10.8

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip intstall -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python","manage.py","runserver","0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

**error message**

> [+] Building 0.1s (2/2) FINISHED
> docker:default   => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
> 0.0s   => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                              0.0s   => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                               0.0s   => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                 0.0s  ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount882053646/Dockerfile: no such file
> or directory

I am trying to integrate docker onto my desktop

Comment: I am no docker expert and things seems correct in your dockerfile. I will only check for the name Dockerfile and you are trying docker build in the same directory where the Dockerfile is.

Comment: What command did you use to create the image and what is the name of your file ? (You can edit your first post with these informations)